# Transfer text field to choice field in separate form

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to have a single-line text field called 'Position Title', in one CognitoForm I created, transfer to a choice field (as one of the options) called 'Position Title' in another CognitoForm so when it is opened I can use the drop down and select from all the position titles submitted in the original form.

I tried the Post Data to website and created the URL as the tutorial instructed but it isn't working.  Is it possible to do make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). We do not offer the ability to transfer the choice field on one form into another form. You can however let users type in their own choice by selecting Radio Buttons as the type and then checking the box next to "Allow Fill In".

[image]

Users will then be able to select a blank text box and type in their own information.

[image]

We use JSON as our data transmission format when posting data to a client's site. When we post to a website we post as JSON. You will need to parse that data on your end. You can have your form post to [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) to see what the data looks like.

Comment: Thanks.  The purpose of the automatic transfer was to avoid different position titles being used- we need both forms to be the same.  If they type it in each form, then we run the risk of the position title being different.  Is this a feature you might could add?

Comment: Upon further review we are looking to add this functionality in the future. We have added this to our idea board(https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP) so that you can follow the ideas progress.